# It is possible to put a bounty on a question which is higher than the own reputation count

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I observed on this question [Which software methodology should I follow when I do research?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/321605/which-software-methodology-should-i-follow-when-i-do-research) that the OP put a bounty on his/her question of 100 points, while she/he has only 31 points.

Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not. The bounty amount is deducted *at the moment of placing the bounty*, so the OP's reputation was 131 points and it is now back to 31. This is mentioned in the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> **- All bounties are paid for up front**

Comment: well, that was quick :)